# Removing self from Global Administrator built-in role is not allowed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

**Question: How can I remove "Security Administrator" role?**

I am using Java APIs to assign "Security Administrator".

The java code looks like this.

```
  final DirectoryObject dirObjectCreated = Objects.requireNonNull(graphClient
                            .directoryRoles(ROLE_TEMPLATE_ID + "=" + SECURITY_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_ID)
                            .members()
                            .references())
                    .buildRequest()
                    .post(directoryObject);
```

This works fine.

When I try to remove this "Security Administrator", I am getting the error

`Removing self from Global Administrator built-in role is not allowed.`

I am tried following URL

Method: DELETE

URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments/y-RKG-FULL-ID

It seems removing the role is not allowed. I looked the example 11 at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-assign-graph

This link at example 11 says

`We prevent users from deleting their own Global Administrator role to avoid a scenario where a tenant has zero Global Administrators. Removing other roles assigned to self is allowed.`

My token has following roles

```
"roles": [
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Domain.Read.All",
    "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory",
    "Application.Read.All"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing everything correct and it seems to me like a bug. I can reproduce the issue. I would suggest to open a support ticket if it's urgent for you.